# pygame subset for android on Python 3+

Tags: pygame

So I have a problem. I have made a little game in pygame with python 3.4. For Python 2.7 there is a way with "pygame subset for android" to build an apk for an android phone. Is there an alternative to make this with Python 3 and pygame?

Answer (score 0):

Try buildozer from kivy, or try [`QPython`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.qpython.qpy&hl=en) on the google play store.

Comment: So is it possible to build an apk with QPython? And does Builddozer support pygame with python 3.4?